# Reopen ejected SD card?

Tags: eject

I'm new to Linux and have Ubuntu 11.04.
After you eject an SD card, how do you reinsert a different one in the same slot?
my computer wont recognize any after the first one and after the initial eject, the drive disappears in the disk utility.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided dmesg output as you insert, eject and reinserted the card.

Comment: I think the problem here is, that what gets ejected is the card reader and not only the SD card. I remember facing such a problem with an older computer - never got it working, though.

Comment: Do you eject it by choosing "eject" from drive's menu on your desktop (or wherever else, I mean - ejecting in your system), or do you just remove the card from the reader?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem before, and it occurred only when I was too quick to insert the other card. The usual solution was to wait about 10 seconds and then insert the other card.

You can also just simply wait for the operations related to the drive to be completed, and then you can simply pull out the first card, wait a few seconds, and insert another.